# How to prove that the $n$-series inequailty

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

consider this inequality

$$\frac{3n+1}{2n+2}<\frac {1^n}{n^n}+\frac {2^n}{n^n}+\cdots+\frac {n^n}{n^n}<2$$

some questions

1.
prove this inequality

2.
does the series converge??

Comment: What is the source of this problem? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Induction might work. Use $2- \frac{1}n$ for RHS.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! To attract answers to your question, please add some context and background information. For example, where did you encounter this problem (e.g. a book, class, real-life)? Please also show your attempt; seeing your work helps us help you. If this is homework, please read [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1803/23353).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

consider well know inequality 
$$\ln{(1+x)}<x,x>-1$$
so we have
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\dfrac{k}{n}\right)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}
\left(1-\dfrac{k}{n}\right)^n<\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}e^{-k}<\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}=\dfrac{e}{e-1}=1+\dfrac{1}{1-e}<2$$
other hand

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\dfrac{1}{2n}\left[\left(\dfrac{k}{n}\right)^n+\left(\dfrac{k+1}{n}\right)^n\right)>\int_{0}^{1}x^ndx$$
$$\Longrightarrow \dfrac{1}{n}\left[\dfrac{1}{n^n}+(2/n)^n+\cdots+\left(\dfrac{n-1}{n}\right)^{n}+\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\dfrac{n}{n}\right)^n\right)>\dfrac{1}{n+1}$$
so 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\dfrac{k}{n}\right)^n>\dfrac{n}{n+1}+\dfrac{1}{2}=\dfrac{3n+1}{2n+2}$$
In fact we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{i^n}{n^n}=\dfrac{e}{e-1}$$